# I want to create a stored procedure by passing input variable and output to be in json format in oracle?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, bind-variables, listagg

We have a requirement to create a stored procedure in Oracle, passing input variables and output to be in JSON format.  I've tried   using `listagg()` but getting error as "result of string concatenation is too long" while executing the procedure.

The expected output has to be in JSON format from the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used xmlagg and it worked
select 
(SELECT RTRIM(xmlcast(XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT(E, columnname|| ',') ) AS clob) ,',')
                    FROM table) ||'}' from dual

Answer (score 1):

A regular select in PL/SQL uses bind variables by default and you might want to have a look at https://github.com/doberkofler/PLSQL-JSON to generate json.